# Can't set a COOKIE in Internet Explorer from a deeply nested domain name

Tags: php, internet-explorer, cookies

My local development sandbox is accessible via a URL like this:

```
http://hello.trunk.world.dev.foobar.local/
```

When I try to set a cookie from here it works on all browsers except Internet Explorer (versions 10 and below). Is there a way to get it to work?

```
setcookie('myCookieName', 'myCookieValue', time()+3600, '/', '.foobar.local');

var_dump($_COOKIE); // Shows nothing in IE, shows the cookie in other browsers
```

Comment: Do you have underscore somewhere in your domain? Because this will make it invalid and it won't work in IE

Comment: @Darhazer You are right, that was the problem not subdomain depth. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those cases in which IE actually is acting according to the standard. Underscores are not valid in domain names, and that's why cookies are not working for the invalid domain name.